# Pusher (React) auto disconnects app (401 error), after 4 hours of inactivity

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pusher, pusher-js

I have a problem with my react app. I use pusher and I recently faced with a problem, that Pusher auto disconnects after a couple hours of inactivity:

Laptop was closed for a couple hours, then I opened it again (token was still valid) and saw:

[image: screenshot]

Any further operations with pusher did not work.
Can anyone give me a hint what is going on with it?
I have already tried the next properties:

```
pongTimeout: milliseconds,
activityTimeout: milliseconds,
pong_timeout: milliseconds,
expirationTime: milliseconds,
expiryDuration: milliseconds,
expiration: milliseconds,
expire: milliseconds,
activity_timeout: milliseconds,
```

Comment: HTTP 401 would indicate you are not authorised - is there some authorisation you are doing? Perhaps the auth token expires after 4 hours? 
Does the error always occur after exactly 4 hours or is it just after a long period?

Comment: Hm, yeah that might be a problem, but matter is token does not expire after 4 hours, it does not expire even after 8 and 12 hours, so problem is that pusher somehow auto disconnect itself after a couple hours of inactivity